# How can you pass an std::istream into a function in a way that allows to pass temporaries?

Tags: c++, istream

I am trying to create a constructor to load a resource from any istream given to it. I cannot seem to figure out the best way to pass the istream parameter into a constructor.

```
Loader::Loader(istream stream);
```

This one is obviosly bad due to object slicing, so no option.

```
Loader::Loader(istream& stream);
```

This is what I am using now and seems fairly alright. It has one significant issue though - you can't give it a temporary since temporaries cannot bind to non-const references! For example, the following won't work:

```
Container():
  mLoader(ifstream("path/file.txt", ios::binary)
{
}
```

This is rather a limitation since I am now forced to store the ifstream as a member variable of Container just to extend its lifetime.

Since the problem is with non-const references, one could have though of this:

```
Loader::Loader(const istream& stream);
```

But since .seek() etc are non-const, this is not an option either...

So, how can this problem be solved in a neat way?

Comment: The `std::istream` has to exist somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if your compiler is c++11 or better you can simply provide a version of the constructor that takes the `istream` as an r-value reference:

`void Loader::Loader(std::istream&& is)`

quick example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct Loader
{
    Loader(std::istream& is)
    {
        read(is);
    }

    Loader(std::istream&& is)
    {
        read(is);
    }

    void read(std::istream& is)
    {
        is >> std::quoted(x);
        is >> std::quoted(y);
    }

    std::string x, y;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Loader& l)
{
    os << "x = " << l.x;
    os << ", y = " << l.y;
    return os;
}


auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace std;

    Loader l(istringstream(R"text("donkey" "horse")text"));
    cout << l << endl;

    istringstream not_temp(R"text("apple" "banana")text");
    Loader l2(not_temp);
    cout << l2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
x = donkey, y = horse
x = apple, y = banana
```

Comment: This makes sense IMO. By providing both a Loader::Loader(std::istream&& is) and Loader::Loader(std::istream& is), and have the former call the latter, you can use it in both ways. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the point in defining such a constructor for each class where it's desired. As I see it, a single centralized solution such as a `temp_ref` function is less code (linearly in the number of classes), and more clear.

Comment: I understand your position(s). Less code (linearly in the number of cases) I agree with. More clear, I would probably take issue with.

Answer (score 2):

The example

```
Container():
  mLoader(ifstream("path/file.txt", ios::binary)
{
}
```

… is ill-conceived, because the lifetime of the temporary would be just the constructor call. Then you'd be left with a **dangling reference**. Using that reference would be Undefined Behavior.

However, technically, in order to be able to pass a temporary to a reference-to-non-`const` formal argument, just define a little helper like this:

```
template< class Type >
auto temp_ref( Type&& o )
    -> Type&
{ return o; }
```

Then you can call e.g. `foo( temp_ref( Whatever() ) )`, but just keep in mind that the lifetime of that temporary is the full-expression that it occurs in.

Comment: If you're using C++11 then the stream should be movable.

Comment: Is it really ill-conceived though? Nothing says that the loader function will store the reference. As long as it uses it to just load data and then discard it, it would be fine?

Comment: @Tobias: Yes, if the use is within the temporary's lifetime all is OK. :)

Answer (score -2):

Passing a pointer to a newly created object would work.

```
Loader(istream * pstream)
{
    try
    {
        // ......

        delete pstream;
        throw; 
    }
    catch(...)
    {    
        delete pstream;                  
    }
}

Container():
mLoader(new ifstream("path/file.txt", ios::binary))
{
}
```

Comment: This is a hideous resource leak waiting to happen!

Comment: More like crash when you pass the address of a stack allocated object.

Comment: @Tobias AND a forced redundant memory allocation.

Comment: @RichardHodges - how is this a memory leak waiting to happen?

Comment: @user93353 if an exception is thrown in the constructor you'll be left with an orphaned istream on the heap - worse, its file handle will still be open.

Comment: right, so there are a few problems remaining:
1) the exception is not propagated so you will end up with a half-constructed object.
2) if the exception happens during the evaluation of the initialiser list or the default initialisation of member variables, your try/catch won't catch it so you're back to square one with a resource leak.
3) you still have a redundant memory allocation
4) you you rely on the caller not passing you the address of a static, global or stack-based istream.
For these (and other) reasons, good c++ design avoids the use of pointers in interfaces.

Comment: @RichardHodges - 1. was planning to put a rethrow, but forgot about it - added it now. 2. There was no initialiser list - hence did not use a function try block. 3. He wanted a temp - there is no other way to have a temp.

Comment: There is an implicit initialiser list. Any member that's not mentioned in the initialiser list is default constructed. If any of these default constructors throw, you have a resource leak. The way to pass a temporary is to pass a temporary, which either of the other two answers allow. If you _really_ insist on passing a pointer, the only way to make it safe is to pass a unique_ptr (or unique_ptr const ref). But why would you when you can simply pass a temporary, which is succinct, simple, supported by the language, unambiguous, safe and requires no special knowledge at the call site?